# Page takes two refreshes for table data to update PHP+HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to make an edit function for my table (pulls from mysql).
In a nutshell the way it works is when you click on an edit button it turns specific text into an input field. A save button also appears next to the field.
The problem I'm having when you click on the 'save' button the page reloads but the table data does not update. I have to reload the page again for the table data to update. Here is my php/mysql insert code:

```
// DEFINING POST VARIABLES
$u_first = $_POST['U_firstname'];
$u_last = $_POST['U_lastname'];
$find_id = $_POST['sid'];

// QUERY DEFINING WHAT TO UPDATE
$query = "UPDATE studentdata SET firstname = ? , lastname = ? WHERE userid = ?";

// PREPARE STATEMENT    
$statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);

//BIND parameters for markers
$results =  $statement->bind_param('ssi', $u_first, $u_last, $find_id);
$statement->execute();
$statement->close();
```

I'm not sure if this matters but here is my table code too:

```
    while($row = $query_results->fetch_array()) {

    // CONVERTS FIRST & LAST NAME INTO A SINGLE VARIABLE
    $NN_first = $row["firstname"];
    $NN_last = substr($row["lastname"], 0, 1);
    $NN_full = $NN_first.' '.$NN_last;

    // PRINTING TABLE ROW
        print '<tr>';
    // MAKING FORM
        print '<form action="example.php" method="POST">';
    // GETS/MAKES HIDDEN USER ID
        print '<input type="hidden" name="sid" value="'.$row["userid"].'">';
    // PRINTS FULL NAME VARIABLE
        print '<td>'.$NN_full.'</td>';
    // PRINTS UPDATE BUTTON
        print '
        <td class="textcenter">
            <input type="submit" class="example-page-btn" name="Update'.$row["userid"].'" value="Update">
            <input type="submit" class="example-page-btn" name="Delete" value="Delete">
        </td>';
    // PRINTS FORM CLOSE
        print '</form>';
    // PRINTS END TABLE ROW
        print '</tr>';

}
```

Comment: is your update code executed before loading table data and output?

Comment: Your form is posted to `example.php`. What does that file contain? The first block of code? The second? Both? Which comes first?

Comment: The file contains both blocks of code. In the order above.

Comment: Unrelated to the answer, but very important nonetheless: 1) you are using PHP to print HTML line by line, which is very difficult to read / prone to syntax errors. 2) You are putting a `form` inside `tr` - I'm pretty sure this is invalid HTML syntax.

Comment: Can you define what is meant by "table data does not update"? Do you mean you don't see the new values in the table upon refresh? Or do you mean the `studentdata` table in SQL does not successfully perform your `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: @light Yes. The page does not display the updated values till I refresh again.

Comment: So the SQL gets executed without issues, but you don't see the new values of `$row["userid"]`, `$row["firstname"]`, `$row["lastname"]` - is that right? If so, where on the page have you assigned values to the variables `$row["userid"]`, `$row["firstname"]`, `$row["lastname"]`? Can you show that code too?

Comment: @light Sure! The values are being assigned my mysql. I am looping through all the rows with a while loop : `while($row = $query_results->fetch_array()) { etc }`

Comment: Please put the code in your question. We can't tell what is wrong with `{ etc }`.

Comment: @light I'm sorry, The second block of code from the original description is inside the `{etc}`.

Comment: Ok understood. For clarity, you should include the `while` in the second block of code, and the SQL statement that was executed to get your `$query_results`. One more thing, your SQL statement in the first block uses `id`, while you use `$row["userid"]` in the second block. Is there a typo somewhere?

Comment: @light Ok will do. And yes that was a typo when writing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make a JSON by your mysql table data and append the data in your table. After successful entry/update , update your JSON.